# How to listen to a "Response not Found" event in Google Forms script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a URL that points to the response of a certain email for a Google Form. In the following format:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../edit#response=...

In case this response exists, the URL redirects me directly to the answer for that particular email.

In case the response doesn't exist, it redirects me to the answers page but it raises a toast at the bottom of the page as following:
[Response not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SU9L.png)

What I'm trying to do is listen to this "Response not found" toast-event in Google Apps Scripts, and act accordingly, doing something such as raising an alert.

But how am I supposed to listen to this event, if I can't run code on the browser scope? (i.e. document.getElementById is not accessible).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: document.getElementById() is a clientside javascript function for use on an active dom in a browser.  But google apps script runs server side.  You have to parse your returned html as a string on the server side.

Comment: From the form script editor you can use formResponse methods and from the linked spreadsheet the event object collects all submitted information in either values or namedValues().

Comment: @Cooper I think this is exactly what I need! Thank you very much! It's clear to me now I've been approaching the problem the wrong way. I've been doing some tests with formResponses, and it seems to have everything I need. I'll come back here with updates on this issue.

Comment: @Cooper ok, you've definitely solved my problem! formResponse methods is the solution I didn't knew I needed. Care to create an answer so I could accept it?